# ¿Cuál es el uso de la etiqueta [push]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

8 preguntas tienen la etiqueta [push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) y el uso que se le ha dado ha sido para:

1. El uso del [framework de notificaciones de Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116167/ayuda-peticion-al-servidor-desde-ajax)
2. El [comando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126954/problema-al-hacer-un-push-en-git-error-403) `push` de git
3. El método `push` de [JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86490/problema-con-array)
4. Las [notificaciones push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67901/android-fcm-mostrar-en-textview-de-activity-mensaje-de-notificaci%C3%B3n-push) en Android

¿Cuál debería ser el uso correcto para la etiqueta?

Comment: Push es una instruccion.. deberia ser quemada y baneada.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la sugerencia de eliminar/quemar la etiqueta [push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) es razonable, realmente esas preguntas no la necesitan y se podrían re-etiquetar con otros valores ya existentes:

- [push-notification](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification): para preguntas relacionadas con las notificaciones push, que debería ir junto a una etiqueta de lenguaje ([android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) o [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)). Esta etiqueta cubriría los casos 1 y 4.
- [git-push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push): para preguntas de Git relacionadas a errores o problemas con la actualización de los ficheros remotos. Esta etiqueta cubriría el caso 2.
- [pilas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pilas): para preguntas sobre `push` en JavaScript (o en otro lenguaje de programación) porque es un método particular. Cubriría el caso 3.

Y quizás nos podríamos plantear renombrar [push-notification](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification) a [notificación-push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notificaci%c3%b3n-push), por aquello de que estamos en español... pero eso ya sería otro tema.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Sólo un comentario: no me gusta pilas -en el caso de JavaScript, la dejaría sin esa etiqueta, sobra con la etiqueta del lenguaje.

Comment: burninate! o como sea que hayan decidido que se dice en castellano :P